# An if-then-else logic to construct constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, nonconvex-programming

I was hoping to get some help in modelling the following logic, I know that it would use some kind of Big M formulation but I am not sure how. Thank you in advance!

$\Omega$ is a set whose values are all binary, $\Omega(n,k)$ is one of the value.

If $\Omega(n,k)=1$, then $p(k,n)\ge 0$, else $p(k,n)=0$.

This question is similar to the following:
[Modelling an if-then-else logic in MIP](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/modelling-an-if-then-else-logic-in-mip)

Comment: What type of variable is $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\Omega$ is a set of variables, as opposed to parameters, you can just write $0 \le p(k,n) \le M_{k,n} \cdot \Omega(n, k)$ where $M_{k,n}$ is a known upper bound for $p(k,n).$

Comment: Thanks for your solution, the method is concise and easy to understand !

Answer (score 2):

I missed the part where $p$ is continuous and just have to be non-negative. Then same as above answer
$p(n,k) \le M\Omega(k,n)$
$p(n,k) \ge 0$
$M$ is upper bound of $p(n,k)$